# SQL data record to HTML form

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, mysqli

So I'm a real noob to SQL. I only just managed to get my head around sending data from a html form to a table in a database.... Please bear with me.

I have a very large form on which I have broken down into 6 sections for each user to fill out. The project I am working on is a career progression based website. It has sections called "About Me", "Employment History", "Education" etc.

The about me page is the first form a use will complete and it will generate a new user account number in the database under the "About Me" table.

I want to take that number and use it on all other forms for the same applicant behind the scenes. How can I do that?

I hope that question made sense and thanks in advance for any help you can offer me.

What I have tried so far is this:

```
<?php
$ApplicantNo = SELECT ApplicantNo from aboutme WHERE EmailAddress='$EmailAddress' AND Firstname='$FirstName';
    <input type="hidden" name='ApplicantNo' value='" . $ApplicantNo . "'>"; ?>
```

Comment: If this isn't pseudo-code, you have quotes missing. Plus, you're injecting HTML into PHP.

Comment: You would not want to expose something as essential as a user id in the html because this can be easily changed

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding this id to the session variable. Then it can  be used on any page in the application.

It may be even better to have them create an account  so the id can always be accessed even if session is ended. you would set the id in the session on each login

`$_SESSION['uid']`

Answer (score 0):

Well to do that you have to use the **SESSION** variable..
First of all you have to execute the `mysql` query correctly

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $ApplicantNo = "SELECT ApplicantNo from aboutme WHERE EmailAddress='$EmailAddress' AND Firstname='$FirstName'";
    $query=mysql_query($ApplicantNo);
    $query_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $_SESSION['app_no']=$query_row['ApplicantNo'];
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name='ApplicantNo' value='\" . $_SESSION['app_no'] . \"'>";
?>
```

So you can use it in this way in other pages and don't forget to write `session_start()` in begining of every page you use the **SESSION** variable.